# How to change type of column table field in laravel backpack?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

So my table would be looks like this one

```
[   // Table
'name'            => 'options',
'label'           => 'Options',
'type'            => 'table',
'entity_singular' => 'option', // used on the "Add X" button
'columns'         => [
    'name'  => 'Name',
    'desc'  => 'Description',
    'price' => 'Price'
],
    'max' => 5, // maximum rows allowed in the table
    'min' => 0, // minimum rows allowed in the table
]
```

So the default for the columns is text, and i want to change it to choice. Anyone have an solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Updating column attributes with migrations. Check documentation:

[updating columns attributes in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#updating-column-attributes)

Comment: May be you can change in backpack with his visual mode, but Laravel Backpack is based on Laravel and migrations are for this cases.